# Rails capybara,fill_in failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have next spec:

```
click_link('Edit')
expect(current_path).to eq(edit_news_path(@news))
fill_in('Body', with: 'Changed body')
click_button('Edit')
expect(current_path).to eq(admin_path)
expect(@news.body).to eq('Changed body')
```

All expectings are passing the test, but not fill_in expecting:

```
Failure/Error: expect(@news.body).to eq('Changed body')

   expected: "Changed body"
        got: "Example"

   (compared using ==)
```

And its all ok on site,every editings both saved,so whats the problem in rspecs?

Answer (score 0):

That usually means capybara can't find the field you mean.

A couple of things you might check: is the label Body linked to the input field via  ? Is there only one field with a label "Body"? You might also try using the id for the field in the fill_in call, like

```
fill_in("content_body", with...
```

Comment: yes,i have only one 'Body' label, and its linked to right input field,also have a problem with destroying:
   
        Failure/Error: expect(@news).to eq(nil)
       
       expected: nil
            got: #<News id: 92, title: "Example Example", body: "Example", created_at: "2015-03-29 19:45:32", updated_at: "2015-03-29 19:45:32">

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `click_button('edit')` seems to have problem. I think that you are not saving the body, you must be having `click_button('save')` 
Use `binding.pry` in between the test statements to check the value of various objects.

Comment: no,'Edit' button fine,as i already sayd - edit action works without a problems on site

Comment: I meant to say ask, what is the name of your button in the view. Can you paste your form code over here.

Comment: news/edit.html.haml :
        `=form_for @news do |f|
  =f.label :title
  =f.text_field :title

  =f.label :body
  =f.text_area :body

  =f.submit "Edit", class: 'btn btn-primary' `